# Jquery Filter() option slow down performance in select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I have 18 select2 dropdown (#menu1, #menu2, #menu3, etc etc) with multiple external choices to filter them. The filters works with no problems at all but this takes about 3-6 seconds in Chrome, the others with the same logic has instant responses.
This is a simplified version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var all = $('#menu1 option');  
var c; // Set by another function
var costo;
var razza;

$('#vanillas').on('click', function() {

// Really Slow
if ((typeof costo === 'undefined') && (typeof razza === 'undefined')) {
    $('#menu1, #menu2, #menu3').empty().append(all);
    $('[id^="menu"] :not(option[data-razza=Vanilla])').remove();
}

// Really Slow
else if ((typeof costo === 'undefined') && (typeof razza !== 'undefined')) {
    $('#menu1, #menu2, #menu3').empty().append(all);
    $('[id^="menu"] :not(option[data-razza=Vanilla])').remove();
} 

// This is fast
else { 
    $('#menu1, #menu2, #menu3').empty().append(all.filter("option[data-costo='x']")).append(all.filter("option[data-costo="+c+"]"));
    $('[id^="menu"] :not(option[data-razza=Vanilla])').remove();
}
    razza = "Vanilla"; 
});
});
```

**EDIT: (give it a context)**
The initial number of option (in the var "all") is 545, when this function take place (#vanillas onclick) the option in the dropdown is 503, and the number of option after this function will be 466.
The "else" output options will be less than 100, so it's ok to be a faster function but it's not that can cause this slow down. To do the same thing on the same number of initial element with another filter it takes 0.02 seconds and the final output it's 11 options or 35 on other similar filtering.

There's a reason for the slow performance or a solution to make it work as the others filters functions (in term of time)?

Comment: If you have many `options` it may be the problem here. Last one is faster thanks to `filter` which removes some of the options.

Comment: @Nathan that's a sure thing when it filter by cost the number of option is less than 300 (on a base of 1200). How can I improve and speed up this function?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. You're asking your browser to render 1200*3 `option` tags, that's why it's so slow. IMO you should review your architecture. Is it necessary to show 1200 options ? Still necessary on 3 select boxes ? Maybe you can implement an input to query the server the values you _really_ need, hard to tell without more context.

Comment: My bad, it's 545 option per dropdown, in the initial selection I need them all and it's loaded via PHP. The first 3 must contain all the option, with this function it will become 503, there's must be a way to do it in a reasonable time!

Comment: Why *must* there be a way to do it? The amount of work that has to be done by a browser whenever a change to the DOM is made is not insignificant. When this is performed several hundred times at once this will be slow.

Comment: Cause for a filter on a bigger number of options takes less time in the same project.

Comment: But do you populate 3 `select` at once ? And if you filter, how many `option`s are generated ? These things matters...

Comment: @NathanP. When the page is loaded PHP populate 18 dropdown (well it's 6 of 3 identical dropdown) with inside a maximum of 545 option and it takes about 3 sec for the entire page. When every filter function go it's really fast except this, every filter can append or remove up to 545 option.  If I only remove option in this filtering the response time it's always slow. This is weird.